# Difference between nest start and node dist/main.js?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, package.json

I work on a project using Nest, where the "start" config in the package.json looks like this:

```json
"start:dev": "nest start --watch",
"start": "node dist/main.js",
```

and I wonder why the the second line does not simply use `"nest: start"`. Both seem to work the same. The [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/scripts) states that:

> `nest start` simply ensures the project has been built (same as `nest build`), then invokes the `node` command in a portable, easy way to execute the compiled application.

I don’t see why anyone would want to run a project without ensuring it was built first. So is there any reason not to use `nest start`? Maybe performance? Are there other meaningful differences?

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking the `@nestjs/cli` is a great *dev* tool, but it doesn't have much use in production. You usually don't have changes to your code that you need to auto-recompile and restart your server with (the `--watch` flag), you don't need to do live debugging (the `--debug` flag) and you *usually* don't need to compile your code once in production, as you should be sending the transpiled JS to production instead of the source code. Due to all of these factors, there's not really a reason to use `nest start` in production.

Locally, however, it's an awesome tool to allow for quick restarts of the server, and to generate files using the `nest g` command. The `nest start` command itself *does* check to see that the project is already compiled, but it only checks that a `dist` exists, and if so it's good, no matter how old that `dist` is, which is why the `--watch` flag is usually better to add to it, so that you always get a recompile to happen.

Answer (score 1):

From the NestJS doc:

> `nest start` simply ensures the project has been built (same as nest
> build), then invokes the node command in a portable, easy way to
> execute the compiled application.

So it's just for simplicity to run production code and just a shorter than two sequential commands: `npm run build` + `npm run start:prod`.
if you sure the code was built you can use `npm run start:prod` otherwise `nest start`.

Answer (score 0):

The two commands serve slightly different purposes and can be used in different contexts.

1. `"start"`: `"node dist/main.js"`

- This command is a very straightforward way to run your application. It directly runs the compiled JavaScript code in your dist directory. It's fast because it doesn't involve any build process. It just assumes you've already built your project and that the dist/main.js file exists. This command can be ideal for production environments, where the project has already been built and tested, and you just want to start it as quickly as possible.

2. `"start:dev"`: `"nest start --watch"` or `"start"`: `"nest start"`

- This command is using the Nest CLI to start your application. The nest
  start command will indeed ensure that your project is built before
  it's run. This can be helpful in a development environment where
  you're actively making changes to your code and you want those
  changes to be compiled (transformed from TypeScript to JavaScript)
  and run immediately. The --watch flag takes it a step further and
  will keep the process running, watching for changes to any files and
  rebuilding and restarting your app automatically whenever it detects
  a change.

The key difference here is between a production environment and a development environment. In production, you want your app to start as quickly as possible, and you know the code isn't going to be changing, so you can run the built JavaScript directly. In development, you want the convenience of having your code automatically built and the app restarted whenever you make changes, even though this process might be slightly slower.

As for performance, the difference is not very significant. The build process doesn't take very long for most projects, and it only happens once when the app starts (or each time you change a file, if you're using `--watch`). The running app's performance won't be affected by how it was started.